# N-queen problem code working only till n=4

Tags: c++, algorithm, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I am trying to solve the N-queen problem (Given an integer n find all ways of placing n queens on a n*n chess board such that no two queens attack each other)

This is my code which works find till n = 4

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;


bool isLegal(vector<int> &board) {
    
    int i = board.size() - 1;
    for (int j=0; j<board.size() - 1; ++j) {
        if (board[i] - board[j] == i - j || board[i] - board[j] == j - i ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

void print(vector<int> &board) {
    for(auto col : board) {
        cout<< col<< "  ";
    }
    cout<< endl; 
}
void print(set<int> &rem) {
    for(auto col : rem) {
        cout<< col<< "  ";
    }
    cout<< endl; 
}

void putQueen(set<int> &rem, vector<int> &board, vector<vector<int>> &ans) {
    cout<< "Call on board  ";  
    print(board);

    if (rem.empty()) {
        ans.push_back(board);
        cout<< "Got answer"<< endl;
        return;
    }

    for (auto p=rem.begin(); p!=rem.end(); ++p) {
        cout<< "Trying : ";
        int col = *p;
        cout<< col<< endl;

        cout<< "Remaining Columns : ";
        print(rem);

        board.push_back(col) ;
        cout<< "Put in "<< col<<endl;
        cout<< "C1"<< endl;
        rem.erase(col);
        cout<< "C2"<< endl;
        print(board);
        if (isLegal(board)) {
            putQueen(rem, board, ans);
        }
        cout<< "C3"<< endl;
        rem.insert(col);
        
        board.pop_back();
        cout<< "C4"<< endl;

        cout<< "Remaining Columns : ";
        print(rem);
        cout<< "Board : ";
        print(board);

        cout<< "Col at"<< col<< endl;
    }
}

vector<vector<int>> findPositions(int n) {
    vector<vector<int>> ret;
    set<int> rem ;

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        rem.insert(i);
    }

    vector<int> board;

    cout<< "Call 1"<<endl;
    putQueen(rem, board, ret);

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    /*
    [1, 3, 0, 2] -> col
     0, 1, 2, 3  -> row
    */
    vector<vector<int>> ans = findPositions(n);

    cout<< ans.size()<< endl;

    for (auto board : ans) {
        for (auto pos : board) {
            cout<< pos<< "  "; 
        }
        cout<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm storing the output as an integer vector where value at ith index denotes queen in ith row is placed on column = val(i.e., vector[i]).
I know there is excessive use of print statements for debugging.
Anyway, for n=6 the code gives segmentation fault when board position is 0 2 4 and I've checked all possibilities of of putting next queen in 1st column of next row.

I can't figure out why as my set is not empty.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: In absence of any comments outlining your reasoning (which would make it much easier to check where what you wrote and what you wanted might deviate from each other), I am looking askance at `j<board.size() - 1` in `isLegal()`. Are you sure?

Comment: In isLegal() I'm checking if the last queen that I placed is not in the diagonal of any existing queen. hence j does not need to go beyond board.size() - 2.

Comment: I tested your code and got a segmentation fault for 1, 2, and 3. Don't concentrate on 4. (Modifying a collection as you iterate over it is usually not a great idea.)

Comment: Looks too complicated to me – I'd just start with a vector filled with values from 1 to n and use [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) until it returns false (all permutations found) – and for each permutation check if it is legal. Your legality check would iterate `for(i = 1; i < size(); ++i) { for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) if(diagonalAttack) { return false; } } } return true;` and if legal copy that vector to the answers.

Comment: Just a side-note: `for (auto board : ans) {` is copying the inner `vector<int>`s as it iterates. You want `for (const auto& board : ans) {` to get a read-only reference without performing wasteful copies. The only time a for-each loop should use plain `auto` is when the values being iterated are primitives, or you actually need copies; otherwise, you typically want a reference of some kind (with `const auto&` being the goto when you're just reading, not mutating or moving-from).

Comment: More specifically, `rem.erase(col)`, when `col == *p`, invalidates `p`, and your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: You mention only having solutions up till "n=4", but there are no solutions for "n=2" or "n=3" and for "n=1" it's obvious :-)

Comment: @molbdnilo got the thing that was causing the error. But still can't pin point what scenario is triggering the segmentation fault. Because `rem.erase(col)` and `rem.insert(col)` are being called several times in the runtime and they behave as I expected, so why only at certain positions does it throw the fault. (For n=6 it does at 0 2 4 after all permutations with 1 being the next value have been checked) .... Anyway replaced set with vector and swithed col to -1 when it has been occupied to get desired result.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means that anything can happen. A program may even look like it's working, even though it's fundamentally broken.

Comment: @Bob__: that was what I meant :-)